# Why it's printing both parent class's and child class's constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

This is test class that creates instance of Sub_Class

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Sub_Class s = new Sub_Class();
    }
}
```

Here is Parent and Child class

```
public class Super_Class {

   public Super_Class(){
       System.out.println("This is Parent Class's Constructor");
   }
}

class Sub_Class extends Super_Class{
   public Sub_Class(){
       System.out.println("This is Child Class's Constructor");
   }
}
```

Constructors aren't herited then why it prints both constructor?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? You can't construct a subclass without also constructing its superclass

Comment: Sub class's constructor calls the parent's constructor at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification, Section "8.8.7. Constructor Body"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7)

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

So, yes, the constructor of the super is not inherited, but it must always be invoked.  And if you do not invoke it yourself, then the compiler will do it implicitly for you.  And if the compiler cannot do it, (because the super's constructor requires arguments,) then you will get a compile-time error.

Answer (score 1):

A per the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

> Note: **If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass**. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.